# Users have access to all stores in REST API level using MAGENTO 2

Tags: php, rest, magento2, magento2.1

i see Magento 2 with no support of independents stores in a same installation. Look, if i want to get a query using REST API:

```
http://localhost/rest/{store code}/V1/categories
```

If i create a user per store using any extension i know, he always can access all stores just changing the store code using REST and a POSTMAN.

My question is: How to block a user in a REST API level only per store. Is it possible? Is there any extension that makes it?

Thanks!